# The method takePicturein the type Camera is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

I am following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html) to implement a camera activity in my Application the issue is i have a function that is suppose to start the camera which is like:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null,
             new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));        
}
```

This is exactly how it is given in the tutorial but here it is giving me error that:

```
The method takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback) in the type Camera is not applicable for the arguments (null, null, PhotoHandler)
```

I tried casting the 3rd argument to `PictureCallBack` as eclipse suggested but thats also not working.
can any one please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhotoHandler` must not be implementing the `Camera.PictureCallback` interface.